# Jade and Express - Block in Block

Tags: node.js, express, block, pug

Little Question to Jade and Express here. For me it is not possible to use Blocks in Blocks ...

So let's assume my layout.jade looks like this:

```
!!!
html
  head
    scripts meta tags and other stuff here...
  body
    block content
```

And a page for example home.jade looks like this:

```
extends layout

block content
  html stuff here
  block table
```

And table.jade looks like this:

```
extends home

block table
  html table here
```

Is this even possible ? I mean, I want to achieve that only the table is rendered in a response, like

```
res.render('table', data);
```

and the view only updates the Table.

Any suggestions ?
Thanks ..

Comment: Why don't you check it? Is there a problem? It would probably be faster then writing this post. :]

Comment: @freakish - sorry, i did it that way, and it's NOT working. Forgot to mention.

Comment: Well, then you have your answer.

Comment: now for that , i asked for suggestions. Are there other ways to accomplish this ?

Comment: I don't understand. You want to render only the table view. But why do you then extend the other views? Why not just call the table view?

Comment: @RickardZachrisson I want to to "refresh" the table with new data without rendering all the rest again.

Comment: Thought about doing it with ajax perhaps? Would solve it I would assume.

Comment: @RickardZachrisson - Could possibly do it ... ill give it a try